# Spark task hanging at [GC (Allocation Failure) ]

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

**EDIT:** Note: An executor will normally emit the message `[GC (Allocation Failure) ]` . It runs it because it is trying to allocate memory to the Executor, but the executor is full, so it will GC in attempt to make space when loading something new to the Executor. If your Executor does this in a loop, it may mean what you are trying to load into that Executor is too big.

I am running Spark 2.2, Scala 2.11 on AWS EMR 5.8.0

I'm trying to run a `count` operation on a Dataset that refuses to finish. What's frustrating, is that it is only hanging on one particular file. I run this job on a different file from S3, no problem - it finishes completely. The original CSV file is @18GB itself, and we run a transformation on it to turn the original CSV into a struct column, giving it one extra column.

My environment's core slaves are 8 instance where each is:

```
r3.2xlarge
16 vCore, 61 GiB memory, 160 SSD GB storage
```

My Spark session settings are:

```
implicit val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("MyApp")
      .master("yarn")
      .config("spark.speculation","false")
      .config("hive.metastore.uris", s"thrift://$hadoopIP:9083")
      .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
      .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
      .config("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
      .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", false)
      .config("spark.executor.cores", 5)
      .config("spark.executors.memory", "18G")
      .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "2G")
      .config("spark.driver.memory", "18G")
      .config("spark.executor.instances", 23)
      .config("spark.default.parallelism", 230)
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 230)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

The data comes from a CSV file:

```
val ds = spark.read
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("delimiter", ",")
          .schema(/* 2 cols: [ValidatedNel, and a stuct schema */)
          .csv(sourceFromS3)
          .as(MyCaseClass)

val mappedDs:Dataset[ValidatedNel, MyCaseClass] = ds.map(...)

mappedDs.repartition(230)

val count = mappedDs.count() // never finishes
```

As expected, it spins up 230 tasks, and 229 finish, except one somewhere in the middle. See below - the first task just hangs forever, the middle one finishes no problem (though is odd - the size records/ratio is very different) - and the other 229 tasks look exactly the same as the finished one.

```
Index| ID |Attempt |Status|Locality Level|Executor ID / Host|                       Launch Time          |   Duration   |GC Time|Input Size / Records|Write Time | Shuffle Write Size / Records| Errors
110   117   0   RUNNING     RACK_LOCAL     11 / ip-XXX-XX-X-XX.uswest-2.compute.internal 2019/10/01 20:34:01    1.1 h   43 min     66.2 MB / 2289538                0.0 B / 0   
0     7     0   SUCCESS     PROCESS_LOCAL  9 / ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal 2019/10/01 20:32:10   1.0 s   16 ms      81.2 MB /293        5 ms         59.0 B / 1   <-- this task is odd, but finishes
1     8     0   SUCCESS     RACK_LOCAL      9 / ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal 2019/10/01 20:32:10  2.1 min     16 ms      81.2 MB /2894845        9 s          59.0 B / 1   <- the other tasks are all similar to this one
```

Checking the stdout of the hanging tasks, I repeatedly see the following the never ends:

```
2019-10-01T21:51:16.055+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-10-01T21:51:16.055+0000: [ParNew: 10904K->0K(613440K), 0.0129982 secs]2019-10-01T21:51:16.068+0000: [CMS2019-10-01T21:51:16.099+0000: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.031/0.044 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
 (concurrent mode failure): 4112635K->2940648K(4900940K), 0.4986233 secs] 4123539K->2940648K(5514380K), [Metaspace: 60372K->60372K(1103872K)], 0.5121869 secs] [Times: user=0.64 sys=0.00, real=0.51 secs]
```

Another note is that before I call the count, I'm calling `repartition(230)` just priot to calling `count` on the `Dataset[T]` to insure equal distribution of data

What is going on here?

Comment: `spark.executorS.memory=...` - is it a typo? I'd also consider scaling down your resource allocation and getting rid of all unrelated config options.

Comment: `spark.executors.memory=` is a valid setting - it's how much RAM to give each executor. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-ha-considerations.html . 5 cores/executor, 16 cores per instance - 1 for the daemon = 15 cores per instance / 5 = 3 executors per  instance. 61GiB memory for the instance / 3 executors = 20 - (10% of 61GiB for overhead) = 18.

Comment: @mazaneicha - I need all of those settings so can't remove them. Which resources would you recommend pairing down?

Comment: AFAIK its `.executor.`, singular, not plural. You're leaving 1 core and 1 GB "overhead" for OS, YARN NodeManager, ResourceManager, plus whatever else is running on a node? That sounds too agressive to me.

Comment: I doubt you need default.parallelism and shuffle.patitions settings. Not sure what else is happening in your app, but as stated, it also doesnt need speculation or any of the hive... options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has something to do with data skew and/or data parsing issues. Note that the problem partition has radically more records than the one, processed successfully:

```
Input Size /  Records
66.2 MB / 2289538
81.2 MB /293
```

I'd check that all the partition files have roughly the same size and number of records. Perhaps line and/or column delimiters are off in either the problem or "good" partition files (293 lines seems to be too low for ~80 Mb file).

Comment: Well - the data is loaded into a `Dataset[T]` prior to doing the count, and none of the `T` fields are `Option[_]`so the parsing would have failed if not. I went and looked again at my input size and records - the `81.2MB/293` records seems off as you noted - but this step completes fine. It is weird thought, because the other 228 tasks are all @81.2MB/@2,200,000. Wouldn't me calling `repartition(230)` properly re-distribute the data though, preventing the skew?

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded"? Spark has a lazy evaluation model. All reads/caching/repartitioning/data transformation calls are only used to build an execution plan DAG. Which is only executed once an action (like count, write, show etc) is encountered.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that prior to the count, there is a `map` transformation from the original DF brought in by the CSV and it is converted into a Dataset[T], since it's a transformation, wouldnt it fail at that step, rather than the count?

Comment: I should also mention I've done a take(n) prior to the count for debugging purposes too, and that also works as expected.

Comment: It turns out the file I was trying to perform operations on was likely corrupted. I couldn't even run a simple `count` on the thing by SSH'ing into the EMR cluster. Giving you the checkmark because ultimately, that is a data parsing issue!